# Crc32 хэширование

Tags: php

Всем привет! У меня такой вопрос. хеширую функцией crc32(); выдаёт результат в 32-битной! примерно так:1268185348, а мне нужно в 16, примерно так 1AF23G11! Если кто знает помогите! Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Просто Fike ссылку дал коментом! там галки то нету! я бы ему 10 галок поставил)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dechex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

> Decimal to hexadecimal
> Returns a string containing a hexadecimal representation of the given unsigned number argument.

Comment: Круто! Спасибо!